# Javascript document["someid"].src works in Firefox, but not in other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I'm trying to do very simple Javascript implementation.

It's with onMouseOver event over diferrent texts and that change one image.

It works perfectly on Firefox, but not in any other browsers.

HTML

```
<div id="foofoo1" onMouseover="imagehover(this);">display image1</div>
<div id="foofoo2" onMouseover="imagehover(this);">display image2</div>
<img id="foo" src="dir/images/foofoo1.jpg">
```

Javascript

```
function imagehover(idfoo){
  document["foo"].src = "dir/images/"+idfoo.id+".jpg";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a non-standard way of doing it anyway.

```
document.getElementById("foo").src = "dir/images/"+idfoo.id+".jpg";
```

This is the correct way to do it.

Comment: Actually, I tried with .getElementById("foo"), but I put .scr instead of .src. I feel stupid after 1 hours, trying to figure out what's happening. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Use `setAttribute`  [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute)

```
document.getElementById("foo").setAttribute('src',"dir/images/"+idfoo.id+".jpg");
```

Comment: I do not understand people down voting without any comments.

Comment: This is wrong. The `.src` property should be set. No need to use `.setAttribute()`. And you're putting quotation marks around the url for some reason. There's no need to wonder why it's being downvoted. All you need to do is look at the accepted answer to know that yours doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense, it was a typo. but is there an issue using setAttribute?

Comment: Well... sort of. When you're in the JavaScript environment, generally you work with objects and properties. Using `.setAttribute()` will work to set the `"src"` attribute because the `.src` property will be automatically changed for you, but it's much more verbose *(and probably slower)* than necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the info... I knew it but just wanted to add a different way of doing it :) But i understand your point... I always try to answer with an alternate option when somebody has answered it already.

Answer (score 0):

Does `document.getElementById("foo")` work (instead of `document["foo"]`)